# How to check whether the iOS device running GPRS / data plan in roaming or not

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, roaming

I want to check whether the iOS device running GPRS / data plan is in roaming or in native location using xcode code / coco touch library?

Can you please help me in that ?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate (albeit with no solution): http://stackoverflow.com/q/12925812/558933

Comment: Its not the perfect Question / Answer you suppose to me. Thank you for your time and comment.